# Is this achieved with a list?

Tags: lists, code

I am new to LaTex. I want to generate the code as shown below. But I don't know how to achieve it? It does not seem to be a `pseudo-code` implementation method. The above marked this is a `list`, but the form of the list I know is `1. 2. 3.`. How can I implement such a code? How to add the outer box and the text on it?
[image]

I used the two-column format. The command \setlength\columnsep{0.25cm} sets the column spacing to 0.25. When I used listing, the result now is:

[image]
The numbers cover the text in the left column. In the top picture, the code is closer to the middle.

I used a thesis template. The address of the template is:  https://www.microarch.org/micro53/submit/micro53-latex-template.zip
Thank you very much

The following is part of the template. This template generates a two-column format. But I did not find the setting in the code. The list generated by the following code will cover the left column.

```
 \documentclass{sig-alternate}
\usepackage{mathptmx} % This is Times font

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[sort,nocompress]{cite}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage[keeplastbox]{flushend}
% Always include hyperref last
\usepackage[bookmarks=true,breaklinks=true,letterpaper=true,colorlinks,linkcolor=black,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=black]{hyperref}

% Ensure letter paper
\pdfpagewidth=8.5in
\pdfpageheight=11in

%%%%%%%%%%%---SETME-----%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\microsubmissionnumber}{XXX}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyhead[C]{\vspace{15pt}\normalsize{MICRO 2020 Submission
      \textbf{\#\microsubmissionnumber} -- Confidential Draft -- Do NOT Distribute!!}} 
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
    basicstyle = \ttfamily,
    numbers = left,
    numberstyle = \footnotesize,
    frame=lrtb
}
%set margin
%\usepackage{geometry}
%\newgeometry{left=0.75in,right=0.75in,top=1in,bottom=1in}
\setlength\columnsep{0.25cm}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

%%%%%%%%%%%---SETME-----%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title{Guidelines for Submission to MICRO 2020} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{firstpage}
\pagestyle{plain}




%%%%%% -- PAPER CONTENT STARTS-- %%%%%%%%

\begin{abstract}

    This document is intended to serve as a sample for submissions to the 53rd International Symposium on Microarchitecture~{\textregistered} (MICRO 2020). We provide some guidelines that authors should follow when submitting papers to the conference.  This format is derived from the ACM sig-alternate.cls file, and is used with an objective of keeping the submission version similar to the camera-ready version.

\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

This document provides instructions for submitting papers to the 53rd International Symposium on Microarchitecture~{\textregistered} (MICRO 2020).  In an effort to respect the efforts of reviewers and in the interest of fairness to all prospective authors, we request that all submissions to MICRO 2020 follow the formatting and submission rules detailed below. Submissions that violate these instructions may not be reviewed, at the discretion of the program chairs, in order to maintain a review process that is fair to all potential authors. This document is itself formatted using the MICRO 2020 submission format. The content of this document mirrors that of the submission instructions that appear on the conference website. All questions regarding paper formatting and submission should be directed to the program chairs.





\section{Paper Preparation Instructions}

\subsection{Paper Formatting}


\begin{lstlisting}[caption = Code for probing one 12-way cache set]
lfence
rdtsc
mov %eax, %edi
mov (%r8), %r8
mov (%r8), %r8
mov (%r8), %r8
mov (%r8), %r8
mov (%r8), %r8
mov (%r8), %r8
mov (%r8), %r8
mov (%r8), %r8
mov (%r8), %r8
mov (%r8), %r8
mov (%r8), %r8
mov (%r8), %r8
lfence
rdtsc
sub %edi, %eax
\end{lstlisting}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`listings`](//ctan.org/pkg/listings). The following is a start:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  basicstyle = \ttfamily,
  numbers = left,
  numberstyle = \footnotesize,
  frame=lrtb
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption = Code for probing one 12-way cache set]
    lfence
    rdtsc
    mov %eax, %edi
    mov (%r8), %r8
    mov (%r8), %r8
    mov (%r8), %r8
    mov (%r8), %r8
    mov (%r8), %r8
    mov (%r8), %r8
    mov (%r8), %r8
    mov (%r8), %r8
    mov (%r8), %r8
    mov (%r8), %r8
    mov (%r8), %r8
    mov (%r8), %r8
    lfence
    rdtsc
    sub %edi, %eax
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can it be centered? The displayed number covers the text in the left column.

Comment: @cyj: You'd have to provide more details/context for your setup for I can help further.

Comment: thank you. I added a little detail in question, don’t know if it’s enough? I hope it can be displayed at the top of this column.

Comment: @cyj: Can you provide some code to reproduce your output? Are you using [`multicols`](//ctan.org/pkg/multicols) or just a `twocolumn` setup? What is your `\documentclass`?

Comment: Thank you a lot. I provided a reproducible code. I used a thesis template.

Comment: @cyj: Add `xleftmargin=2em` to your list of options: `\begin{lstlisting}[caption=...,xleftmargin=2em]`. Adjust `2em` to suit your needs.

Comment: thank you very much. Wish you all the best.